# Higher isomorphic homotopy imply isomorphic cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was wondering if one could provide intuition to the following result. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are path connected.

If $\pi_n(X)\cong \pi_n(Y)$ then for all $n$, then $H^*(X)\cong H^*(Y)$.

This sounds like a general hurewicz type argument but I dont know

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99302/spaces-with-equal-homotopy-groups-but-different-homology-groups,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426212/stronger-two-space-formulation-of-hurewicz-theorem-about-homotopy-and-homology-g?rq=1

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stronger two-space formulation of Hurewicz theorem about homotopy and homology groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426212/stronger-two-space-formulation-of-hurewicz-theorem-about-homotopy-and-homology-g)

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks yes it does! I asked a new question of what I had in mind.