# If two CW complexes have isomorphic homotopy groups, are they homotopy equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I denote with $\pi_{i}$ i-homotopy group. If I have $X,Y$ CW-complex and $\pi_{i}(X)=\pi_{i}(Y)$ for all $i$. Can I say that $X$ and $Y$ are homotopic equivalent? What type of equivalence is it?

Comment: IIRC, if you have a map $f:X\to Y$ that induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups, then it is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/88943 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53399/

Comment: Moreover, please see: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3286/) and [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3399/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot say that $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent if $\pi_i(X) = \pi_i(Y)$ for all $i$. This is because the definition of homotopy equivalence requires that there is some continuous map $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ that is invertible up to homotopy. Hence the isomorphisms $\pi_i(X) \cong \pi_i(Y)$ need to be induced by such a homotopy equivalence $f$.

The standard counterexample is $X = S^2 \times \Bbb R P^3$ and $Y = S^3 \times \Bbb R P^2$. These groups have isomorphic homotopy groups (this follows from the fact that they both have fundamental group $\Bbb Z/2$ and universal cover $S^2 \times S^3$), but $H_5(X) \cong \Bbb Z$ and $H_5(Y) \cong 0$ as $X$ is compact and orientable but $Y$ is compact and nonorientable. Homotopy equivalent spaces have isomorphic homology groups, so we see that $X$ and $Y$ in this example could not possibly be homotopy equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

If there is a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ which induces an isomorphism $\pi_i(X)\stackrel{\sim}{\to} \pi_i(Y)$ for every $i\geq 0$, this map $f$ need not be a homotopy equivalence for arbitrary topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, but it is by definition what is called a [weak homotopy equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_equivalence_%28homotopy_theory%29). However, it is a [theorem of Whitehead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem) that if $X$ and $Y$ are both connected and homotopy-equivalent to CW complexes, then any weak homotopy equivalence between them is in fact a true homotopy equivalence.

To answer your question as written, even if $\pi_i(X)\cong\pi_i(Y)$ for each $i$, there need not be a map $f$ which induces these isomorphisms, and they need not be homotopy-equivalent. There is an example in the Wikipedia article on the Whitehead theorem, linked above.